Who is the Pharaoh of the Exodus?
Which Pharaoh was reigning in Egypt during the Exodus according to our mesorah? Do any traditional Jewish sources discuss his name?

If you're asking based on Jewish tradition, why is the archaeology tag relevant?

Is archaeology at necessarily at odds with tradition? Whats the problem exactly?

It's not necessarily at odds, it's just that Jewish tradition typically pulls out names of pharaohs from the Tanach, while archeologists (unless discussing a biblical text) usually use names from external texts and/or archeological findings (for example, archeologists generally prefer calling Shishak Shoshenq because that's how he's called in Egyptian texts). So the odds of a traditional source we have at hand containing a name otherwise known only from the latter group are slim to none. In other words, I think the archaeology tag isn't relevant here.
